# In NestJs can I use an interceptor and the @Response parameter status setter?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-fastify

I have a NestJs application that uses an interceptor to wrap all http responses much like the example in the docs https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors ...

```
@Injectable()
export class TransformInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>> {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<Response<T>> {
    return next.handle().pipe(map(data => ({ data })));
  }
}
```

For most endpoints this is good enough, but I've found some instances where I want to set the response code based on some logic in the controller, e.g.:

```
@UseInterceptors(TransformInterceptor)
@Post('some-path')
async someFunction(
  @Response() reply: Fastify.FastifyReply,
) {
  return reply
    .status(isATeapot ? HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT : HttpStatus.OK)
    .send(someData);
}
```

But, in this latter case the interceptor gets called with `undefined` and the response that hits the wire is just the raw data.

Is there a way to get both the interceptor and the branching in the status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Response({ passthrough: true })` and don't `.send()` the response, to be able to just set the HTTP code and  let Nest still handle the response

```js
@UseInterceptors(TransformInterceptor)
@Post('some-path')
async someFunction(
  @Response({ passthrough: true }) reply: Fastify.FastifyReply,
) {
  reply
    .status(isATeapot ? HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT : HttpStatus.OK)
  return someData;
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks! ... it's ok that the `reply.status` call is a dangling promise?

Comment: Didn't realize that was a promise. You could `await` it if you need to

Comment: Adding `await` seems to not resolve so that is not viable. But, looking more carefully at https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/68914519a3fd65ce65ba8db8962940eecf7f0fc8/types/reply.d.ts I'm not convinced it actually is a promise (I thought it was because eslint was telling me as much, but maybe eslint is just checking for the presence of a `then` function).

Comment: Also, "patthrough" should be "passthrough" above in the inline code. Thanks again for the pointer!!